# How to add image button in quill.js toolbar in angular 7 using ngx-quill?

Tags: angular7, quill, ngx-quill

I'm using ngx-quill for integrating quill.js in my project as mentioned on this link.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-quill

```
<quill-editor></quill-editor>
```

Using this tag I get the editor and toolbar but I want to add image button on the toolbar as well.

Comment: If anyone can suggest any better editor then please go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to add image option in my toolbar using the quill-editor-toolbar.

```
<div quill-editor-toolbar>
 <span class="ql-formats">
  <button class="ql-image" [title]="'Image'"></button>
 </span>
</div>
```

I wrapped this inside `<quill-editor>`